Are planes through the origin the only position vector self-tangent surfaces?
Are there any surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (other than planes through the origin) such that each position vector lies in the respective tangent plane at that point?
If the surface is given by say $\phi:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, with coordinates $(s,t)\in U$ this is equivalent to ask if $\phi$ satisfies
$$\phi = a\phi_s + b \phi_t,$$
with $\phi_s$, $\phi_t$ denoting the partial derivatives and some functions $a,b: U \to \mathbb{R}$.
Other than planes through the origin, this seems impossible to me and maybe it's trivial but I don't know how to prove it.
Edit: We also have cones. Are there others?

Any union of rays from the origin has the "position in tangent space" property, so we just have to unclude enough rays to get a surface.  So, draw an arbitrary (potentially singular) curve on the unit sphere and your surface is the union of rays from the origin through the points on that curve.

You can prove that such a surface has zero Gaussisn curvature. Such ruled surfaces are classified, and only planes and cones meet your criteria.
